# While using camera plugin in flutter, my front camera is not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

I used the camera plugin in flutter, and whenever i switch it to front camera, it doesn't work but my rear camera is working fine. A white screen appears out of nowhere and after that, whenever i try to change it from rear to front, it doesn't work. I wrote a very simple logic and I don't think that my logic is incorrect and giving me that error, but still, to be sure, can someone check it and explain me the problem.

I tried front camera on emulator, as well as on a physical device too. Same thing is happening on both of them.

My plugin version  - `camera: ^0.7.0+2`

Here is the code snippet -

```
String cameraPosition = "Rear";

 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium, imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg);
    cameraValue = _cameraController.initialize();
    _fetchAssets();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
      value: 025,
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 1.0,
    )..repeat();


/* some code */

RotationTransition(
                        turns: _animation,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.flip_camera_ios,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            setState(() {
                              if(cameraPosition=="Rear") {
                                cameraPosition="Front";
                              }
                              else if(cameraPosition=="Front"){
                                cameraPosition="Rear";
                              }
                            });
                            _cameraController = CameraController(
                              cameras[
                                cameraPosition=="Rear" ? 0
                                : 1
                              ],
                              ResolutionPreset.medium,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: You can use Image_picker instead.
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: @EhsanAskari yeah i will try that, but can you tell me why is this happening?

Comment: I havn't used the **camera** plugin. I just prefer **image_picker** because it is better than **camera** in terms of *pub points*, *popularity* and *likes* on [pub.dev](https://www.pub.dev)